# Долго выполняется запрос, почему

Tags: php, mysql

```sql
SELECT * FROM c_lees
inner join c_price_list on c_lees.id_price_list=c_price_list.id
inner join c_price on c_price.id_price_list=c_lees.id_price_list
inner join c_propel on c_propel.id_price_list=c_lees.id_price_list
inner join c_impel on c_impel.id_price_list=c_lees.id_price_list
where c_lees.id_price_list=1
```

UPD
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Добавила индексы, как мне советовали ( пункт 2 в ответе)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не помогло. Долго выполняется

Comment: А `EXPLAIN` не объясняет? Еще структуру таблиц бы посмотреть. Ну или хотя бы индексы проверить. И сколько записей в таблицах...

Comment: @cyadvert 100% индексы. При нормальных индексах до 1.000.000 в каждой скушало бы и не подавилось с таким запросом.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: Постройте `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM c_lees inner join ...` и приложите результаты к своему вопросу.
Так же не плохо бы понимать, как устроены Ваши таблицы, т.е. их структуры, индексы, количество данных и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько способов оптимизации:

1. Построить `EXPLAIN` запроса
2. Добавить индексы по `*.id_price_list`
3. Сменить на `inner join` на `join`
4. Построить временную таблицу с индексом на `id_price_list`:

```sql
create temporary table tmp as (
SELECT * FROM c_lees
where c_lees.id_price_list=1);

CREATE INDEX id_price_list ON tmp (id_pl) USING BTREE;

SELECT * FROM tmp
inner join c_price_list on tmp.id_price_list=c_price_list.id
inner join c_price on c_price.id_price_list=tmp.id_price_list
inner join c_propel on c_propel.id_price_list=tmp.id_price_list
inner join c_impel on c_impel.id_price_list=tmp.id_price_list
where tmp.id_price_list=1;
```

Comment: `inner join` и `join` одно и то же

Comment: При оптимизации важно учитывать чтоб  c_lees.id_price_list и c_price_list.id, имели одинаковую размерность. Т.е. поля по которые используете в join имели одинаковую размерность.

Comment: @korytoff, 2 сделала не помогло... Долго выплняется

Comment: @RRR ответ не мой